# How can I run a for loop through a recycler view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recycler view in my application, and instead of executing an onclick listener, I want to click a button outside of the recycler view, which instructs the app to go through all the items in my recycler view and perform operations on items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a public method in your adapter to get the list

```
public List<Model> getList(){
    return modelList;
}
```

Get the list anywhere

```
List<Model> listToModify = adapter.getList();
```

Loop through the list and modify it, then set it to the adapter or call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: the important part to understand is the fact that a recyclerview is managed by an adapter, so make changes to the adapter, not the recycler

Comment: I used this and it worked, however now when I use the search bar to search for items in my recyclerview - and since it's dynamic search, the position of items in recycler view changes on search, and hence the logic that I wrote for the particular items in the for loop gets messed up. How can I fix that?

Comment: The recycler view works fine when I reload the activity, however, when i run the for loop it messes up the activity until I refresh.

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for sharing, got it :) I am notifying the adapter after the change as well, but it does not behave according to the logic, can you help?

Comment: i don't see anything like this mentioned in your current question @IanBell, so at this point you'd just be adding additional questions on to the original one. as your original question stands, this post is sufficient to answer it. if you have other questions, be sure to include more details in code into your future questions

Comment: @a_local_nobody can i edit this question and add the new problem that has arised?

Comment: probably better to post a new question

Comment: sure, I will do that